# Hover effect in header menu "About Us" is always triggered on my home page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am building a website for friends of mine and I stumbled upon a bug that I can't figure how to get rid of and I created an "About Us" section on the home page, and the "About Us" button in the header menu links to an anchor right above this section. 
However, the hover effect for the "About Us" button is always triggered on the home page (screenshot bellow)

[Hover_effect_bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtvLg.png)

After inspecting the element, I figured that the bug might happen because of the "current_page_item" class (a default wordpress class), but I couldn't find why it would trigger the hover effect (here is what I could find about the class effects) :

```
.main-navigation li li.current_page_item a:hover,
.main-navigation li li.current_page_item a:focus,
{
        color: #fff;
}
.navigation-top .current_page_item > a 
{
    color: #767676;
}
```

Any idea what causes this to happen ?

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read and answer if you can!

I wish you a pleasant day !

Comment: can you display your HTML?

Comment: Have you got a live version you can link to? or as @Caelan said above, give us some more code to look at so we can help?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answers, for some reason mail notification were disabled so I didn't see that you did ^^'.

I searched more, and I found out that my first hypothesis was wrong : it was the current-menu-item class that bugged. I simply disabled it and everything was fine. I still don't know the exact reason why it was a problem in the first place, however.

You can find a live version of the website here : www.euro-batim.fr

(the current-menu-item still exist in the style sheet, however, I turn it into commentaries). If anyone is interested, I can do some extra digging to find what exactly created the problem.

Have a nice day !